# Symfony2 returns class does not exist on entity load

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to load a object from my File entity, but symfony keeps returning 
"Class Frontend\FolderBundle\Entity\Role does not exist", but i can use it from the subfolder entity without any problems or warnings

I have the following entity's:

```
Frontend\FolderBundle\Entity\File:
type: entity
table: file
fields:
id:
  type: integer
  id: true
  generator:
    strategy: AUTO
filename:
  type: text
user:
  type: integer
manyToOne:
folder:
    targetEntity: Frontend\FolderBundle\Entity\Subfolder
    inversedBy: files
    joinColumn:
      name: subfolder_id
      referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }


Frontend\FolderBundle\Entity\Subfolder:
type: entity
table: subfolder
fields:
id:
  type: integer
  id: true
  generator:
    strategy: AUTO
name:
  type: string
  length: 255
manyToOne:
    folder:
        targetEntity: Folder
        inversedBy: subfolder
        joinColumn:
            name: folder_id
            referencedColumnName: id
oneToMany:
    files:
        targetEntity: File
        mappedBy: folder
manyToMany:
roles:
  targetEntity: Frontend\UserBundle\Entity\Role
  inversedBy: subfolders
  joinTable:
    name: folder_rights
    joinColumns:
      subfolder_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
    inverseJoinColumns:
      role_id:
        referencedColumnName: id
lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Getting al the role's a folder has from a subfolder is working fine.

I have cleared the app/cache and the doctrine cache, but that doesn't do the trick..

If you need more information/code fragment's please ask and i will provide them.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the Subfolder.php entity. There was a addRole function with a reference to the wrong bundle with the right entity.